# Proof explanation: T is unitary $ \iff $ $ T^*T = I $

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

**Theorem:** T is unitary $ \iff $ $ T^*T = I $
**Proof:**
$ ( \rightarrow ) $ If $ T $ is unitary, then for all $ u,v  \in V$ we have that $ \langle u,T^* T v \rangle = \langle Tu, Tv \rangle = \langle u , v \rangle $ hence $ T^* Tv = v $ for all $ v \in V $, meaning $ T^* T = I $.
$ ( \leftarrow ) $ If $ T^* T = I $, then for all $ u,v \in V $ we have that $ \langle u,v \rangle = \langle u , T^* T v \rangle = \langle Tu , Tv \rangle  $, hence $ T $ is unitary.

**My question:** I haven't understood in the  " $ ( \rightarrow ) $ " part where we said $ T^* Tv = v $.
We arrived to $ \langle u,T^* T v \rangle  = \langle u , v \rangle  $, how from here I deduce that  $ T^* Tv = v $? I tried using linearity property of inner-product as follows:
$  \langle u,T^* T v \rangle  - \langle u , v \rangle  = 0 \rightarrow \langle u,T^* T v - v \rangle  = 0 $ , however now I got stuck and couldn't proceed.
In general I know that:
if $ V $ is an arbitrary vector space over some field $ \mathbb{F} $, suppose an inner-product $ \langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle : V^2 \to \mathbb{F}  $ is defined on the vector space.  Then it is not necessarily true that if $ \langle u ,v \rangle =  \langle u ,w \rangle  $ for arbitrary $ u,v,w \in V $, then $ v = w  $.
Also, it is not necessarily true that if $ \langle u, v \rangle = 0 $ then $ u = v $.

Therefore, by having $ \langle u,T^* T v - v \rangle  = 0 $ , how does one deduce $ T^* Tv = v $ ?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: All the answers below are essentially the same correct answer. These answers show you that "the only vector orthogonal to all vectors in an inner product space is the zero vector".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that $u$ is arbitrary. You can choose $u=\lambda(T^*Tv-v)=\lambda w\neq0$, and by axioms of inner product $\langle\lambda w,w\rangle\neq0,\,w,\lambda\neq0$. As the product is in fact equal to zero, either $\lambda$ or $w$ is zero, but as $\lambda$ can be arbitrarily chosen from the scalar field $w=0$, that is: $(T^*T-I)v=0$ for all $v$. If $T^*T-I\neq\bf 0$, then there exist $v$ for which the product is not zero. Again, as $v$ is arbitrary, we have that $T^*T-I=\bf0$ assuming a non empty vector space.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You have $\langle u, (T^*T - I)v \rangle = 0$ for all $u,v$. Take $u = (T^*T - I)v$, to get $$\|(T^*T-I)v \| = 0$$ for all $v$. Can you conclude?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The scalar product is non-degenerate, i.e. if $\langle u, v\rangle = 0$ for all $u$ implies $v = 0$.